# How to integrate Basecamp with Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, basecamp

How do integrate project attachments and messages and between Basecamp and Dropbox?

Is there an application which can integrate Dropbox with Basecamp in such way so that I have all Basecamp attachments and messages inside my Dropbox? I.e., if just edit a file in Dropbox it will be uploaded into Basecamp automatically?

Comment: If an answer provides a satisfactory solution, you could/should click the grayed check mark below the answers voting mechanism. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used their service, but [CloudHQ](https://www.cloudhq.net/) seems to offer what you need.

From their [website](https://www.cloudhq.net/dropbox) about the Basecamp / Dropbox integration:

> CloudHQ simplifies management of Google Docs, Basecamp, and Dropbox files 
>   Manage all your Dropbox and Basecamp files directly from a Google Docs interface 
>   CloudHQ will continuously synchronize Dropbox, Basecamp, and Google Docs 
>   CloudHQ can also backup Basecamp projects and Google Docs to Dropbox

Answer (score 4):

One service called Zapier (disclaimer, I'm a cofounder) offers exactly this (plus a lot more), I invite you to check it out. We have the ability to send [Basecamp Attachment to Dropbox](https://zapier.com/z/05/zapbook/basecamp/dropbox/671/send-basecamp-attachment-dropbox/) and also [Sync New Dropbox File to Basecamp](https://zapier.com/z/i3/zapbook/dropbox/basecamp/756/sync-dropbox-file-basecamp/).

It looks a lot like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O31gV.png]

If you have any questions about how we do this, I am more than happy to answer them: just email me at myfirstname@zapier.com.

Comment: The problem with Zapier is that if I modify a file it will not replace it :( And it I do something on Dropbox (i.e., delete or modify a file) it will not automatically replace it with version from Basecamp.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use of [cloudHQ](http://cloudHQ.net) service. Real time and continuos synchronization by cloudHQ will keep track of files for changes and copy files with a very short delay after the change has occurred.
Here are step by step instructions on how to setup to synchronize your Basecamp projects with Dropbox: [blog cloudHQ](http://blog.cloudhq.net/post/9960523835/set-it-and-forget-it-real-time-synchronization)